# add span in paragraph after complete word count to 150

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a paragraph and I want to add a span tag, so that when the word count reaches 80, it closes the last span of paragraph before closing the paragraph tag.

Comment: What have you tried already?  Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I Just count the words of paragraph and unable to find the position of word which occurred at 80th index.

Comment: Could you add an example showing your point?

Comment: Yes sure
 Suppose I have a paragraph with 200 words and I want to highlighted all words which occurred after 40 words.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh he meant an actual code example

Comment: Yup, you may want to show some relevant code for us to work on. Maybe you can add relevant HMTL code to showcase your work. There you can explain what your exact requirement is.

Comment: In html I have a paragraph in <p> tag


// str2 has paragraph with 200 words which come from the database
str2 = val.replace(/\\/g, " ");
            str = str2.replace(/\//g, " ");            
            var wom = str.match(/\S+/g);            
                    
            return{
                charactersNoSpaces: val.replace(/\s+/g, '').length,
                characters: val.length,
                words: wom ? wom.length: 0,
                lines: val.split(/\r*\n/).length
            }

Comment: Please edit your question and add this code there with the HTML part if possible. Don't worry about editig. We'll fix it.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh please put this into the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to add span after 80th word
You can get the text inside the p element and add span after 80 words After making the changes replace the old p element with new one.

```js
p = document.getElementById("myP");
text = p.innerText;
textArray = text.split(" ");
newtext = textArray.splice(0, 80).join(" ") + " <span> "+ textArray.join(" ") + "</span>";
p.innerHTML = newtext;
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="myP">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to highlight text after 80 words instead of 80 characters.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks Its working